# Display axis.y.text in white

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to have a plot where the axis.y.title and the axis.y.text are displayed in white.

I could use:

```
theme(axis.text.y=element_blank())
labs(x='x-axis', y=element_blank() )
```

But these will completely remove them.

I would like to have them on the plot but displayed in white.
How can I do this?

Comment: You should not use `y=element_blank()` in the `labs` part of your code. That belongs in the `theme` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
theme(axis.title.y = element_text(colour = "white"),
      axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "white"))
```